# /etc/hosts file with resolved dns machine asociated with other name

Tags: linux, dns, host

In linux, is there a way to create a alias related to a dns resolved machine name?
I mean, if i have a dns resolved machine with name DSX01M, can i add a /etc/hosts entry this way?

DSX01M databaseMachine

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my own question:

Steps to resolve:
1)Define in file /etc/host.aliases pairs of values with this structure:

ALIAS_IP  DNS_MACHINE_NAME

2)Add into /etc/environment file

export HOSTALIASES=/etc/host.aliases

3)REload environment file:

source /etc/environment